# How can I count the number of columns in a MySQL table using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I can select the number of rows returned by a query when I select everything by doing the following:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM `foo`.`bar`;
```

However, I now want to select how many columns are returned. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: There's one. The "column" that contains the count of all the rows in the table.

Comment: Do you really need this inside mysql or just inside your application? if the latter, which language is it written in?

Comment: Inside my application. I am trying to write an function that takes a MySql query as a parameter and returns a 2d array and obviously the amount of columns and rows differs each time, in C#!

Comment: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM foo.bar;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `information_schema` database.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS numcols
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE 
  TABLE_NAME = 'bar'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'foo'
```

To put the two together, use:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo.bar) AS numrows,
  (SELECT 
      COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS numcols
    FROM COLUMNS
    WHERE 
      TABLE_NAME = 'bar'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'foo'
  ) AS numcols
```

Answer (score 2):

`DESCRIBE someTable` and then `mysql_count_rows()` on the result.

Since the question has to do with C#, I think this should work - but I haven't done C# in a long time.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(#...);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;
command.CommandText = "DESCRIBE sometable";
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
Reader.FieldCount # this has the count of rows, and hence columns
```

Comment: The questioner is using C#, so PHP's `mysql_count_rows()` won't help him here. You answered before he clarified this in a comment though, I think...

Comment: Yeah @burhan answered before I clarified this! Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If your table `mydb.mytable` is MyISAM, the following should work well:

```
SELECT
    row_count,column_count
FROM
    (
        SELECT table_rows row_count
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'mydb'
        AND table_name = 'mytable'
    ) rowcount,
    (
        SELECT MAX(ordinal_position) column_count
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = 'mydb'
        AND table_name = 'mytable'
    ) columncount
;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's InnoDB, but I didn't specify this previously.